# Playing a haptic when frontmost app receives a notification

Tags: swift, notifications, watchkit, watchos, watchos-4

In Apple's documentation for [Frontmost App Behavior](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextension), it is stated that

> "[...] when the frontmost app receives a notification, rather than displaying the notification alert, it could play haptic feedback or a custom sound and then update its user interface."

However, I am having trouble implementing this. Right now, after my button is pressed, I declare the app as frontmost before I schedule a notification:

```
@IBAction func StartButtonPressed() {
    WKExtension.shared().isFrontmostTimeoutExtended = true
    scheduleNotification()
}
```

When the notification is received while the app is in the foreground, it plays a haptic:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    //MARK: Handle foreground notification here
    WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success)
    print("Foreground notification received")
    return
}
```

This works while the user's wrist is raised, but it does not when the user lowers his wrist after tapping the button.
The console prints *Foreground notification received* both when wrists is raised or is lowered.

If instead of playing a haptic, I set `completionHandler([.alert,.sound])` the notification alerts the user both when wrists is raised or is lowered. This is the behavior I want, but only with a haptic.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Check `applicationState`. `play(:)` method doesn't work if the status is `background` or `inactive`.

> This method has no effect when called while your shared WKExtension object's applicationState property is either background or inactive. By default, you cannot play haptic feedback in the background. The only exception are apps with an active workout session. For more information, see Running in the Background in HKWorkoutSession.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice/1628128-play

Comment: In watchOS 4 frontmost apps gain the advantage of waking from the background to receive notifications. Why does the notification not play the haptic if the app is woken from the background?

Comment: @Patrick This is what apple documentation says. Are you sure the status is foreground when you run `WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success)`?

Comment: Seems it should work. It seems doesn't need to set this but worth to try. [LINK](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52630)

Comment: I checked whether the app is in frontmost state as, per documentation, frontmost apps in watchOS 4 are specifically able to play haptic feedback from the background. Before watchOS 4 it was already possible to play haptics with a Workout Session, but shouldn't it work without one now? If `applicationState. play(:)` does not work, what is the correct way of making this work?